# when selenium runing, can selenium close and detect window alert if apear window alert?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

when selenium runing, 
can It close and detect window alert,
if apear window alert  ?
I need it, because window alert apear random in web.
this is pseudo code

```
try:    
    if window alert is apear:
       context.driver.switch_to.alert().dismiss()
except NoAlertPresentException:
   print('no alert')
```

Comment: Is this alert appear once per specific scenario or occurrs on any random action??

Comment: ok then you need to block alert by using JavaScript...try with provided answer..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying alert occurs randomly and you can't know when it occurs, then you should use `execute_script()` to disable the alert occurrence every time when the page has changed or refresh means you need to execute JavaScript one time when page has changed to disable alert :

```
driver.execute_script("window.alert = function() { return true; }")
```

This Java script override the functionality of alert, so you need to execute once  it every time page load. When it executed alert box will never occur until page refresh.

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: ah thaks i will try it

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox() //or Chrome("path to chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("url")
browser.find_the_element_by_id("someID")

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                   'Timed out')

    alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()
except TimeoutException:
    print "There is no alert window."
```

You can modify 10 to whatever time delay you desire.

Comment: If alert randomly occurs one any action then how it could be handled by its your code?? As OP says...As I see it just handle if alert occurs after launching URL..what would be if alert occurs after any action??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur, good point, thanks. I need to put more thoughts in my answer.